# How can I compose tailwind classes into more higher-level, semantic classes?

Tags: tailwind-css

With Tailwind, I can do something like this:

```html
<img class="inline-block h-6 w-6 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="inline-block h-6 w-6 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="inline-block h-6 w-6 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="inline-block h-6 w-6 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="inline-block h-6 w-6 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="inline-block h-6 w-6 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="inline-block h-6 w-6 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="inline-block h-6 w-6 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="inline-block h-6 w-6 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" src="...src..." alt="">
```

But that type of markup has lots of problems for me. I'd much rather do something like this, a "fake" way using sass mixins of composing disparate UI styles into a larger level emantic class:

```
.user-avatar {
  @include inline-block;
  @include h-6;
  @include w-6;
  @include rounded-full;
  @include ring-2;
  @include ring-white;
}
```

```html
<img class="user-avatar" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="user-avatar" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="user-avatar" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="user-avatar" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="user-avatar" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="user-avatar" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="user-avatar" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="user-avatar" src="...src..." alt="">
<img class="user-avatar" src="...src..." alt="">
```

Is anything like this possible in Tailwind?

Comment: While you can do this, Tailwind [heavily discourages it](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/utility-first) and is mean to be used directly, without semantic classes.

Comment: I read that. Still trying to get my head around this approach, and I see some advantages. But see many more disadvantages so far.

Comment: I don't care if the Tailwind team discourages it, you might as well be writing inline styling the way most people use Tailwind. It's bloody illegible and makes component files bloated. Make the Tailwind unions inside the component file and you have something useful for the developer who comes after you (or even you when you re-visit it months later).

Answer (score 2):

In your index.css you can [extract classes with @apply](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply). You can red up in the docs about advantages and disadvantages.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .user-avatar {
    @apply inline-block h-6 w-6 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="user-avatar" src="...src..." alt="">
```

Comment: Yes to this. Using class after class and abbreviation on abbreviation is meaningless to the developer coming behind you (as well as inconsiderate). This use of tailwind is much better, although an actual design system would be 100x better.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, just saw the `@apply` directive. That must be the thing.